Movie where two lead characters each believe the other is a TV character
What is the movie in which the female lead is an hispanic EMT and the male is involved with organized crime, but the twist is that they each think that the  other stars in a TV show about the life they themselves are actually living.  At some point they each speak from the TV screen to each other, leading the woman to wonder if she's losing her mind and the man to think it's some sort of surveillance of him by her through his TV.  Eventually they try to connect, always failing until the woman goes to the TV studio and uses a typing machine to change and eventually destroy the script of the man's show, thereby saving his life.  
The movie was available under the Science Fiction category on either Amazon or Netflix earlier this year but no longer seems to be available.  I would say it is only a few years old and both the man and the woman are played by top rate actors but they are not real famous. 

The Frame (2014)

From Jamin Winans, writer and director of the cult smash hit, INK, comes a mind-bending science fiction thriller about two strangers who find their lives colliding in an impossible way. Alex (David Carranza) is a methodic cargo thief working for a dangerous cartel. Sam (Tiffany Mualem) is a determined paramedic trying to save the world while running from her past. Suddenly and mysteriously, Alex and Sam's lives crash into each other and the fabric of reality is ripped from underneath their feet. Taking on the very root of fate, destiny, and their own existence, Alex and Sam race through a maze of an ever-changing universe while being pursued by a demonic man determined to erase the world.

