Trying to figure out an obscure syfy mystery movie
My Dad was once watching a random movie, and I was busy, so I was catching bits and pieces, and then I sat down and caught the last 30 minutes. 
The premise is that a guy and a woman (a nurse I believe) see each other's life on TV. And they are watching the future, by the end I think they both realize this and she sees his death by murder, so she tries to save him, but it warps reality, because I guess he was destined to die, so the world ends up going barren and the guy is all alone, and he tries to leave his room, but the world keeps dragging him back into the room somehow.  
But he also finds a typewriter in a room full of hanging light bulbs during one of his escapes; the typewriter is writing what is happening at the moment and it is titled "The Edge" or something like that, which I believe was the title of the movie (but whenever I Google that I find 3 different movies with the same name). 
Then when he is giving up stuck in the room, a violin shows up, and he starts to play it because I think he played it as a child. So he plays the violin, and the world starts to warp back and he ends up back right before everything warped away, and he is able to save the nurse lady from dying as well, and then they hold hands or just look at each other or something. Then it ends. 
It's an obscure movie, and it's not super new, but not that old either, I believe it was from 2006 or 2009, or somewhere around that time. I'd appreciate the help if you know the title of the movie. I really want to see the whole thing from start to finish and my dad doesn't remember the title of the movie either.

What language was the movie in? Where was it produced (US? England? Elsewhere?)? Were there any actors you recognize in it?

Could be On the Edge

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/62690/movie-where-two-lead-characters-each-believe-the-other-is-a-tv-character/62695#62695

Could be The Frame (2014)

............. Late one evening, as the two have their televisions on they realize that they are broadcast live from their living rooms on the others TV set. They say hello, panic, and turn off their TV's. Each handles the impossibility in a different way – Sam expresses to her Therapist she may be losing her mind and Alex believes the cartel or cops have him under surveillance.
Alex visits his mentor Noah (Cal Bartlett) who is sick and elderly but who seems to be the only person Alex has in the world. Noah senses Alex is in danger and reminds him he's living in a dark world of his own creation and sends him home with the violin Alex played as a child. Alex is reluctant to take the violin as it is a reminder of something painful in his past – a clue we received when he almost accidentally ruined a photo of him with his parents and the violin as a young boy.
Alex and Sam continue to see each other randomly through their televisions and attempt to unwind the mystery by setting a meeting point at a bridge then at her apartment. Both are met with bizarre interactions with Alex's Cartel Boss showing up in one form on the bridge in his world, Sam's Therapist showing up in another form on the bridge in her world and in front of her apartment as a dark character riding a bizarre black tar-spewing bicycle. We realize these characters are one in the same crossing the boundaries between their worlds and morphing into different forms. We also realize that Sam and Alex have the additional connection of music between the two worlds – Sam hums a beautiful melody from the bridge and Alex taps his foot to the same count and we see a mysterious vibration around them. 
......... Alex opens the door to the vacuous room and hears typing on the far end. As he walks toward the sound of the typewriter, he sees a projection of himself in that moment repeating into infinity. He turns back and stares directly into the camera – aware for the first time that the camera is the entity who is watching him. He approaches the typewriter and sees a full script sitting in the paper tray called 'The Frame'. The script describes the exact moment we're seeing, Alex becoming aware of the script and storyteller and writer. He stumbles backward in disbelief and the left side of the camera frame hits him in the back. He moves in the opposite direction and finds the other side of The Frame. After challenging both sides, The Frame lifts him up and tilts him backwards and he mysteriously wakes up at home.


I can't say about the OP, but it seems to be that movie.

I have also highlighted important plot points.
